# Python: Saving a set of timeseries data in a pandas dataframe as a csv

Tags: python, dataframe, csv, time-series, read.csv

I have generated data from a stochastic simulation and saved them as lists of values in a dataframe.
[DataFrame_Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nGbCR.png)
Where $\delta x$ is the index and $MSD$, $t_MSD$ is the time series values and times respectively. I have also had this issue when trying to save large sets of trajectories, where each entry becomes a list of thousands of trajectories, each containing a list of timeseries values.

However, when I save them as a csv file each entry becomes a string, and it becomes very difficult to work with that data later. Is there a better way to save this than the standard df.to_csv('file.csv') method?

I am hoping to save each list in a way that it is easily read back in as a trajectory. Without needing to create an new csv file for each trajectory timeseries.

Comment: Use `df.to_parquet(...)`